# SSIS Change Columns Types

Tags: sql-server-2008, type-conversion, ssis

I need to know that How to convert `nvarchar(255)` to `varchar(50)` in SSIS Type Conversion?

I have tried converting my `nvarchar(255)` to `DT_STR(Unicode)` but still it is not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe you want to try something like this in `Derived Column` SSIS element:

```
(DT_STR, 50, 1252) SUBSTRING([String],1, 50)
```

The cast formula is :

```
(DT_STR, «length», «code_page»)
```

Because you want to change from `unicode` to `varchar`(How to convert `nvarchar(255) to varchar(50)`), you need to know code page of varchar. Code page is [Character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

Usually you need to use code page which is in your SQL Instance, SQL Database, SQL Column.

If you try to write this new string in you table, there is column with property COLLATION, value can be not empty or be empty database default...

I found this page about [Code page architecture](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186356%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), there is written how to relate SQL Collation with Code page.

Answer (score 1):

```
SSIS Data Type         SSIS Expression                        SQL Server

string                 (DT_STR, «length», «code_page»)        char, varchar
Unicode text stream    (DT_WSTR, «length»)                    nchar, nvarchar, sql_variant, xml
```